# Golang Ошибка - cannot use Id (type interface {}) as type string in field value: need type assertion

Tags: golang

Добрый день, использую сессии отсюда

```
 "github.com/gorilla/sessions" WbSocket

 "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
```

Сначала создал сессию, как и написано на оф.сайте
Такой вариант работает:

```
 session, _ := store.Get(r, "SessionId") // r- Request 
 log.Println("Значение из сессии Id=", session.Values["Id"], " и FIO=", session.Values["FIO"])
```

Нужно ещё с этими данными работать и я их сохраняю...
Но такой вариант не работает

```
var ActiveClients = make(map[int ] ClientConn)

    type ClientConn struct {
        websocket *websocket.Conn
        Socket_Id int    
        User_Id string
        FIO string
        Role string   
    }

    func SockServer(ws *websocket.Conn) {
        session, _ := store.Get(r, "SessionId")  
        Id =session.Values["Id"] 
        FIO =string(session.Values["FIO"])
        Role =session.Values["Role"]
        sockCli := ClientConn{ws, Soc_Id,Id,FIO,Role}
        ActiveClients[Soc_Id] = sockCli
        log.Println("Клиент подключился сокет=", Soc_Id, ".id- ", Id, " ФИО- ", FIO, " Роль- ", Role)
    }
```

Пишет

```
cannot use Id (type interface {}) as type string in field value: need type assertion
```

здесь `sockCli := ClientConn{ws, Soc_Id,Id,FIO,Role}`

И для `FIO` и `Role` тоже такое-же.
Почему в консоль он `string` тип выводит, а тут ругается?

**Обновление** Спасибо Vadim Shender, решил

```
Id , _ := session.Values["Id"].(string) 
FIO , _ := session.Values["FIO"].(string) 
Role , _ := session.Values["Role"].(string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что, если заглянуть в исходный код библиотеки, `session.Values` имеет тип `map[interface{}]interface{}`, чтобы в нем можно было сохранять любые значения, то есть получаемые вами значения `Id`, `FIO`, `Role` имеют тип `interface{}`, как более общий, а не `string`.

То, что эти значения нормально выводятся с помощью `Println` --- это следствие того, что все эти значения реализуют интерфейс `Stringer`.

Если вы знаете, какого типа на самом деле хранятся данные в переменной типа `interface{}`, вы можете осуществить явное преобразование этого типа с помощью *type assertion*. Например, зная что `FIO` -- это строка, вы можете явно преобразовать к этому типу, и тогда использовать его как строку.

```
FIOstr, ok := FIO.(string)
if ok {
    // пробразование успешно, в FIO на самом деле была строка
    // FIOstr имеет тип string
    //   и вы можете его использовать как строковое значение FIO
}
```

Так же вы можете поступить с остальными полями, например, если все они у вас строковые, то код будет примерно таким (проверку на ошибки я тут опускаю, но учтите, если тип будет не верный, без проверки ваша программа завершится аварийно):

```
...
Id := session.Values["Id"].(string)
FIO := session.Values["FIO"].(string)
Role := session.Values["Role"].(string)
sockCli := clientConn{ws, Soc_Id, Id, FIO, Role}
...
```

P.S. Очень советую вам почитать хотя бы вот [это](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). Даже вот [на русском](http://eao197.narod.ru/desc/short_effective_go.html) нашел, когда в Google вбил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я написал так Id , _ := session.Values["Id"].(string) 
FIO , _ := session.Values["FIO"].(string) 
Role , _ := session.Values["Role"].(string)

Comment: Учтите, что так в случае ошибки программа не вылетит, но строковые переменные будут пустыми.